# MySQL select with exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form to allow the updating of a position allocated for an item.

The position menu lists all positions not already allocated.  However I want to have the position of the item being edited (and therefore allocated to this item) to be selected in the list.

The question is how can I show all positions not allocated to items and also have the position of the item being edited show as selected?

Note that the position table allocated column is set to either N (Not allocated) or Y (allocated to an item).

```
$query_pos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM position WHERE SUBSTRING(position, 1, 1) = '$room' AND allocated = 'N' ORDER by position ASC");
while ($row_pos = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_pos)){
    if($row_pos['position'] == $position) {
                  echo "selected='selected'";
                }
echo "<option value='" .  $row_pos['position'] . "'>" . $row_pos['position'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: You wrote this question in the context that we know what your database and code structure are.  I, personally, have no idea what "allocated" means in this question.  You said you want to have the position of the item being edited selected then you said you want the allocated position selected, so which is it or are they the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query to a UNION solved the problem:

```
$query_pos = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM position WHERE position = '$position') UNION (SELECT * FROM position WHERE SUBSTRING(position, 1, 1) = '$room' AND allocated = 'N' ORDER by position ASC)");
while ($row_pos = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_pos)){
echo "<option value='" .  $row_pos['position'] . "'>" . $row_pos['position'] . "</option>";
}
```